# Mediaplayer NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I use mediaplayer at my application (mp3 sounds for ringtones). My application working correctly but I see error report on google play developer console (only some users) Where is the problem, I don't know, thank you (I tested every sound)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    soundname= new String[]  {"Sound1","Sound2","Sound3","Sound4","Sound5","Sound6"}; 
    soundfile= new int[] {R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound2,R.raw.sound3,R.raw.sound4,R.raw.sound5,R.raw.sound6};

    this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

    TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("position");

    txtProduct.setText(soundname[position]);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundfile[position]); 

    Button btnplay= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnoynat);
    btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                mediaPlayer.start();         
        }
        });
```

Error log; (mediaPlayer.start();-->SingleListItem.java:60)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.zilsesleri.SingleListItem$1.onClick(SingleListItem.java:60)  
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: your mediaPlayer value is null.  Check the return of MediaPlayer.create, and see if its returning null. It does that on any error.  Most likely your resource is bad, although if you have too many previous unreleased media players that could also cause a problem.

Comment: Perhaps this happens when people click "too fast" before your media player is loaded? You should see if your media player is ready before calling it then.

Answer (score 0):

Android can only allocate a certain amount of MediaPlayer objects, this requires the devloper to release any MediaPlayer object once done with it, by calling `mediaPlayer.release();`

unfortunately many developers don't practice that, which causes the MeadiaPlayer pool of objects return null instead of allocating new ones.

To read more about this: [MediPlayer API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29)

anyway, you may want to check for null and handle this in a way that fits in your app.